# Breeze: Expand bringing back results but not showing on client

Tags: breeze

I have the following entity:

```
public class Return : IAuditable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /* Other properties */

    public virtual ReturnReason ReturnReason { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ReturnItem> ReturnItems { get; set; }

    public Return()
    {
        ReturnItems = new List<ReturnItem>();
    }
}
```

I then perform an EntityQuery to fetch a `Return` by Id as follows:

```
            var entityKey = new EntityKey('Return', id);

            return EntityQuery.fromEntityKey(entityKey)
                .expand('ReturnItems, ReturnReason')
                .using(manager)
                .execute()
                .to$q(querySucceeded);

        function querySucceeded(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
```

The following oData call is made:

```
Breeze/Returns?$filter=Id%20eq%2015&$expand=ReturnItems%2CReturnReason
```

The problem is, `return.returnItems` is an empty array, even though I know this `Return` entity has items attached to it. But `return.returnReason` is populated correctly. And when I go to that URL in the browser, I can see the populated ReturnItems navigation property (I aplogize for my poor cropping ability!):

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure why it is empty when I `console.log(data)`?

Comment: (r)Return is a keyword in javascript and I am surprised you see no issues from using it as an entity name.  Where are you defining your metadata?

Comment: From the server: Breeze/Metadata . I have an Action in my BreezeController which pulls down the metadata

Comment: When you call manager.getEntities do you see the return items in the list?  Console log it before and after your query, pay attention to the navigation properties of the return item if it is there

Comment: I see ReturnItems as a navigation property on Return, however, I don't see Return as a navigation property on ReturnItems. Could that be the problem? But my ReturnReason also doesn't have Return as a navigation property but that works fine?

Comment: Yes, Breeze needs to know which Return that the ReturnItem is part of the collection of.  Check my answer and make sure that the stuff I put in there isn't causing you an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that your Return references a collection of ReturnItems (which EF is glad to return, apparently) but that ReturnItem is missing the reference back to Return.

```
public class ReturnItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /* Other properties */

    public virtual Return Return { get; set; }
}
```

Another note is that your Return constructor is instantiating the ReturnItems as an IList<> but inherently it should already have been constructed, just without values.

Comment: The problem was the missing navigation property on ReturnItem. Strange that this worked fine with ReturnReason, which also doesnt have the navigation property back to Return?

Comment: Had the same problem, Breeze does not seem to "recognize" the automaticly generated (EF Code First) foreign keys on one-to-many relations. Explicitly adding a property, eg `public int ReturnId { get;set; }` on the `ReturnItem` class fixes that.

Comment: I don't think it is a Breeze specific thing - try getting that entity and then calling ReturnItem.Return.Id in your ASP.NET MVC controller and Return will be null as well.